# How do I fix the PATH thing in Environment Variables?

Tags: environment-variables

I was an idiot and put ffmpeg into the PATH thing alone instead of using the ;, and now my cmd can only do dir and ffmpeg. How do I fix this? What do I set the PATH variable to? Please help, my discord bot is screwed up because it doesn't have node.js working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below paths:

C:\Tools\Python\Scripts\;C:\Tools\Python\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Tools\SysinternalsSuite\;C:\Program Files\CVArchiverAddin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped me out so much!

Comment: It wasn't letting me before and was saying for me to wait a minute before I do